# Select Case Function asking for Return Value

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write to Select Case functions, one for two excel worksheets and one for a range of cells. The functions are used to index the sheets and ranges for a sorting procedure. However, the Functions are asking me for a return value, and I am not sure what value to return. I can't return my parameter. Basically, I want my sort sub to loop through both sheets and both ranges and sort the sheets in the select ranges in the function.

If there is a better approach, I am also open to suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
Dim xlWSEmployee As Excel.Worksheet = CType(CType(xlWB.Sheets("byEmployee"), Excel.Worksheet), Excel.Worksheet)
Dim xlWSPosition As Excel.Worksheet = CType(CType(xlWB.Sheets("byPosition"), Excel.Worksheet), Excel.Worksheet)

    Public Function SheetsToSort(Index As Long) As Excel.Worksheet

            Select Case Index

                Case 1 : SheetsToSort = xlWSEmployee
                Case 2 : SheetsToSort = xlWSPosition


            End Select

            ***Return (?)***

        End Function

        Public Function GetRange(index As Long) As Excel.Range

            Select Case index

                Case 1 : GetRange = xlWSEmployee.Range("A1")
                Case 2 : GetRange = xlWSPosition.Range("W1")



            End Select

            ***Return (?)***

        End Function

        Sub Sort_Sheets()


            Dim refSheets As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim sortRange As Excel.Range
            Dim x As Long


            'This is Step 6 when the frmDataImportSplash is activated.

            'The key formulas only work if the data is sorted properly. The procedure
            'below sorts each sheet by the required field. Look at the public_Declarations module
            'for the pass byRef.

            For x = 1 To 2 Step 1

                refSheets = SheetsToSort(x)
                sortRange = GetRange(x)

                With refSheets

                    .Sort.SortFields.Clear()
                    .Sort.SortFields.Add(Key:=(refSheets.sortRange), SortOn:=XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, DataOption:=XlsortDataoption.xlSortNormal)

                    With .Sort

                        .Header = XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .Orientation = Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns
                        .SortMethod = Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
                        .Apply()


                    End With

                End With

            Next x

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Return` statements rather than the legacy `FunctionName = ReturnValue`, and then, if you go past the `Select` statement, it must be an error, surely?

```
Public Function SheetsToSort(Index As Long) As Excel.Worksheet

   Select Case Index
       Case 1 : Return xlWSEmployee
       Case 2 : Return xlWSPosition
   End Select

   Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")

End Function

Public Function GetRange(index As Long) As Excel.Range

   Select Case index
       Case 1 : Return xlWSEmployee.Range("A1")
       Case 2 : Return xlWSPosition.Range("W1")
   End Select

   Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index")

End Function
```

Comment: Multiple Returns are very discouraged. Use a variable to store the value and a return at the end of the method

Comment: @Dubas - excuse me? Multiple returns are perfectly legitimate in modern languages where resource cleanup will occur no matter how the method exits.

Comment: @Damien_The_Ubeliever . Is not a problem of resources is a problem of "Best Practices" and "Coding Conventions" to make code better. More readable, and easy. Multiple "return" sentences are usually discouragend in all code conventions to prevent "strange" problems of code maintenance. Your code is perfectly valid but not really perfect as durable example.

Comment: @Dubas - Single return (much like 2 vs 4 vs 8 spaces for tabs) tends to be a battle ground with little possibility of ever convincing the other side that they're incorrect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Ubeliever.. Spaces vs tabs is a code organization  battle ground but "return" in the middle of methods is a problem that makes really sense in big project with a group of developers. If one developer changes the code of other developer big method in a method with returns its required more time to check if the method flow is correctly and has no problems.

But. You are correct that this are "code suggestions" and can be interpreted in different manners

Comment: @Dubas - the opposite can also be argued - (assuming that you think a large method makes sense and isn't a sign that it should be refactored already) - an early return instantly lets you know "if we've followed the code down this particular path, the result is now determined, and the remaining 40 lines of code take no further part in changing this value"